# Handling browser native click before dom:loaded

Tags: javascript, onclick, cross-browser, prototypejs, dom-events

I have an issue with Cross-Browser native events vs CallBack events.

I have an HTML link "Click Me" with a given `href=""`. On `dom:loaded` I attach a function to this link (to do Ajax Stuff).

JavaScript code is loaded at the end of the page to follow YSlow Recommandation.

**Issue**:

If you load this page really quickly (pressing F5) then click on link then

- the `alert()` is not called
- the link is followed (reloading the page)

It happens when the server lags. In fact the page has not finished loading and the browser execute the code.

**Demo**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <a href="#toolate" id="action">Click Me</a>

    <!-- According to YSlow Recommandation load at the bottom -->
    <script src="../js/lib/prototype.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
    <script>
      /* <![CDATA[ */
      document.observe('dom:loaded', function() { 
        $('action').observe('click', function(event){ alert("click"); Event.stop(event); });
      });
      /* ]]> */
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Turn Around**:

A turn around is to add `onClick="return false;"`:

```
<a href="#toolate" id="action" onClick="return false;">Click Me</a>
```

It works for lags but not for quick click. And I don't like this kind of turn around because  my goal is to remove the `onclick` on all `<a href="">`

Comment: Can you just disable the control and then enable it when the document is finished loading?  In other words, if you can handle the click before page load, don't allow clicks until page load.

Comment: Agree but how do you say to browser: "dont follow ahref until document finish loading" ? You can use JavaScript but engin has not started yet.

Comment: I added a Demo:
http://files.getdropbox.com/u/255810/Jalios/Demo/Shield/shield.html

Comment: What is your objective with this page? To have links that do nothing until the page is loaded, at which point the javascript takes over? If so, remove the href component. Are you looking for graceful degradation? If so then your href should end up doing the same thing as the javascript action so clicking it before page load shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Precisely !
- Sometimes I will do this.href in JS code + graceful degradation.
- Sometimes I can't and need link to do nothing.

If I remove the href component is it valid HTML ? I thought it becomes an anchor ? That's why I often see href="#"

Thanks

Comment: Awesome. I've gone ahead and put my 2cents in an answer now that I feel I understand what you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done many many test on our CMS on many browsers.

Sorted by speed:

1. JavaScript can't execute before a really fast click
2. onclick="return false" works fine in most case
3. JavaScript doing 2.) onLoad is too slow but could be enought
4. DIV using as shield brings other issues and is not a good choice

Answer (score 1):

You could look into this:

> JQuery has a handy little function that
>   launches your javascript as soon as
>   the Document Object Model is ready…
>   which happens before the page has
>   finished loading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   //
 Your code here... 
});
```

[via](http://15daysofjquery.com/quicker/4/)

You could also put a big disabled div in front of everything while the page is loading to forbid clicking, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Not sure if I got your question right, let me know if I didn't

Comment: My function might need to work with the DOM that should be ready. 

On the Exemple, if an onClick on the <A> will not be called if user click quickly. Javascript Engine is not ready I think

We tried the big DIV shield technique but it's a little bit cludge ;)

I thought it would be a common problem but may be there is no "clean" solution.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have things pretty well in hand, and all you're looking to do is create some links which do *nothing* in areas where graceful degradation is not possible.

In these cases I suggest a link with the following format:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Linktext</a>
```

This link should functionally do absolutely nothing with javascript enabled or disabled.

**Important Notes**

1. The number zero in the void is absolutely necessary. Internet Explorer will complain otherwise.
2. The use of "javascript:void(0);" is strongly discouraged by Microsoft because odd things can happen. To avoid the majority of the bugs, do not wrap anything but text in your void(0) links.
3. Before you make a decision make sure to carefully consider if adding "javascript:void(0);" is really a better solution than adding an onclick which returns false.

**On removing the href attribute:**

Removing the href attribute from a link is valid XHTML. Despite being valid XHTML, your link will lose its automatic link styling. No more underline, no more colors, no more hover, and no more automatic color change if the link is visited.

You can't fix the lack of styles with CSS either due to the spotty support of :hover in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is good to know that javascript:void(0); should be better that "return false". But I was looking for something more global. Can I remove the href like you said in the comment ? is it valid XHTML ?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the href attribute and it is valid html. However, your link ceases to be a link and you lose some functionality because of that. I've updated my answer with specifics.